# Incorrect number of dimensions stock price

Tags: r

I am trying to use the data from column 6 aka the adjusted stock price. I want to find the monthly returns for multiple stocks. I keep getting an error when looking at the 6th column of the stock. 
Here is my code.

```
ticker <- c('DPZ','SPY','AMD','AAPL','TSLA')

Portfolio1 <- getSymbols(ticker[1], src="yahoo", 
from='2014-01-01', to='2018-12-31', auto.asign = TRUE)
Portfolio2 <- Portfolio1[, 6]

my.portfolio <- monthlyReturn(Portfolio1)

for( i in 2:length(ticker)){
  Portfolio1 <- getSymbols(ticker[i], src="yahoo", 
from='2014-01-01', to='2018-12-31', auto.asign = TRUE)
  Portfolio2 <- Portfolio1[, 6]
  my.portfolio.a <- monthlyReturn(Portfolio2)
  my.portfolio <- cbind(my.portfolio, my.portfolio.a)
  }
```

Second question is whether or not this loop will create an xts with all 5 monthly return values?

Comment: `getSymbols` is not a base R function. You need to tell us what packages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getSymbols` the data is stored in the ticker name by default and not in the name that you are assigning it to.

```
library(quantmod)

Portfolio1 <- getSymbols(ticker[1], src="yahoo", 
                     from='2014-01-01', to='2018-12-31', auto.asign = TRUE)
Portfolio1
#[1] "DPZ"
```

If you subset this value, you get the error that you get

```
Portfolio1[, 6]
```

> Error in Portfolio1[, 6] : incorrect number of dimensions

which makes sense since `Portfolio1` is just a vector and 1-dimensional object. The actual data is present in the name of the ticker.

```
head(DPZ)

#           DPZ.Open DPZ.High DPZ.Low DPZ.Close DPZ.Volume DPZ.Adjusted
#2014-01-02    69.65    69.65   68.74     68.94     407300     64.57759
#2014-01-03    69.01    69.25   68.81     68.98     415500     64.61507
#2014-01-06    69.11    69.40   68.68     69.10     799600     64.72745
#2014-01-07    69.54    69.97   69.35     69.67     487000     65.26139
#2014-01-08    69.62    70.18   69.41     69.78     851400     65.36441
#2014-01-09    70.12    70.59   69.54     70.28     576500     65.83280
```

So we can get all the data of the symbols together and use `lapply` to bind them.

```
getSymbols(ticker, src="yahoo", 
             from='2014-01-01', to='2018-12-31', auto.asign = TRUE)

data <- setNames(do.call(cbind, lapply(ticker, function(x) {
                          Portfolio1 <- get(x)
                          monthlyReturn(Portfolio1[, 6])
         })), ticker)

 head(data)
#                   DPZ          SPY         AMD        AAPL          TSLA
#2014-01-31  0.02422370 -0.025913218 -0.13164557 -0.09496826  0.2085942488
#2014-02-28  0.11967181  0.045515825  0.08163265  0.05751062  0.3494845521
#2014-03-31 -0.02334707  0.008295903  0.08086253  0.01995296 -0.1485233499
#2014-04-30 -0.03364960  0.006951531  0.01995012  0.09939627 -0.0026864860
#2014-05-30 -0.02594769  0.023205889 -0.02200489  0.07870922 -0.0005772043
#2014-06-30  0.01229755  0.020645189  0.04750000  0.02766200  0.1554122028
```